# Installing a python C package into a bin folder

Tags: python, c

I would like to know how to have setup.py install c modules locally.  Locally as in not in `/usr/local/python..` and not in `~/local/python...`, but in `[where_all_my_code_is]/bin` and I can import it from scripts within the [where_all_my_code_is] folder.

I have some c code.  src/foo/foo.c

```
#include <Python.h>
static PyObject * foo(PyObject* o) {
    PyObject* five = PyInt_FromLong(5);
    return PyNumber_Add(&o, &five);
}
static PyMethodDef funcs[] = {
    {"foo", (PyCFunction)foo, METH_VARARGS, "foo, foo and more foo"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
PyMODINIT_FUNC initaddList(void){
    Py_InitModule3("foo", funcs, "do the foo");
}
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='foo', version='1.0',
    ext_modules=[Extension('foo', ['src/foo/foo.c'])])
```

Now, instead of installing this into my whatever /local/python folders or whatever, I want the code to be in a bin folder right there next to the module.

e.g.

```
~/My_python_project
     ./src
         ./foo
             ./foo.c
         ./some_code_that_imports_foo.py
     ./bin
         ./foo
             ./my_importable_foo.so
```

some_code_that_imports_foo.py:

```
import foo
print(foo.foo(10))
# prints 15
```

What is the appropriate/nicest way to accomplish this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

setup using

```
$ python3 setup.py install --root . --install-lib lib
```

add local `lib` path to the python path

```
$ export PYTHONPATH:$PYTHONPATH:./lib
```

Now python scripts in `.` can import the `c` modules we just compiled.
Something fancier would need to be used for the exact scenario I suggested in the question, but the general procedure should apply.

limitations? possible pitfalls? brittlenesses?

Answer (score -1):

you would have to create custom package for the type of os you are using, deb or rpm or ebuild these system level tools  install files into /usr/bin and /usr/lib instead of your local builds which go to /usr/local or user builds ~/local.

Comment: I knew that this was a possibility... The question specifically requests not this thing...